# Include PHP files depending on Wordpress Templates being used

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress for my site. The site uses many different PHP page templates to display information to the user. At the moment I include all PHP files necessary for posting data to the backend of the site in a common functions.php file e.g. require_once("function1_functions.php"); require_once("functions2_functions.php"); etc

The issue I am having is all of my functions#_functions.php files are loaded on every page, I don't want this. There is an IF statement you can use in WordPress that will allow you to put call certain files on a page depending on the template (page) the user is currently on but this doesn't work for PHP files.

```
if (is_page_template( array('pagetemplate-about-us.php') )) {
    // call JS files here that will only show on the "About us" page
    require_once("functions_about_us.php"); <-- This doesn't work. 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By default WordPress loads functions.php each time you load pages.

Comment: Yeah I know, That's why I include all of the code relating to what files I want to be opened on each page there. I am looking to find out how to include PHP files within functions.php that will load only on certain pages.

Comment: Try to add specific functions file at the head of specific page file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that does work but It would be good to have it localized all within the functions.php file, so if for whatever reason I decide to rename a functions file I don't have to go through 7+ templates and update the required file each time.

Answer (score 1):

The Conditional Tags which control what content is displayed with conditions (such as `is_page_template()`. **Note** these only work after the `posts_selection` action. So here the setup function is actioned at `wp` action, just after `posts_selection`.

More info here on [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

```
if (!function_exists('theme_php_include_setup')):
   function theme_php_include_setup() {

      if (is_page_template( array('pagetemplate-about-us.php') )) {
         require_once("functions_about_us.php");
      }
}
// apply conditions at appropriate WP action 
add_action('wp', 'theme_php_include_setup');
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have a few of these set up already for each pagetemplate I have to include common JS files related to each page and furthermore JS files for each individual page too. The Functions_about_us.php example does not work using this method, unfortunately! I must be missing something...

Comment: ok, are you using `wp_enqueue_script()` to load js with `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook ?

Comment: Yeah, I am doing.